# Нажатие только определенный div

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код.

```js
function open_block() {
  if ($("#block1").attr("data-open") == "1") {
    $("#block1").css("height", "300px");
    $("#block1").attr("data-open", "2");
  }
  else {
    $("#block1").css("height", "50px");
    $("#block1").attr("data-open", "1");
  }
}
```

```css
#block1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#block2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1" data-open="1" onclick="open_block();">
  <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы `div id="block1"` разворачивался только по нажатию на div `id="block1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать проверку на элемент который вызвал событие

```js
function open_block() {
  if (window.event.target.id != 'block1') return;
  if ($("#block1").attr("data-open") == "1") {
    $("#block1").css("height", "300px");
    $("#block1").attr("data-open", "2");
  }
  else {
    $("#block1").css("height", "50px");
    $("#block1").attr("data-open", "1");
  }
}
```

```css
#block1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#block2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1" data-open="1" onclick="open_block();">
  <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Корректнее будет проверять событие из аргумента, а для переключения визуального состояния - использовать класс:

```js
$('#block1').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target === this)
    $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
});
```

```css
#block1 { width: 200px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid; background: #ded; }
#block2 { width: 150px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid; background: #ddd; }
#block1.is-open { height: 300px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

div №2 входит в div №1 поэтому так происходит убери div №2 из div №1 и тогда все получится

Comment: Это не выход из данной ситуации.

Comment: почему же?)))))